# React Navigation App Structure Tabbar visible

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, instagram

I have simple image that illustrates the issue

[image]

this is the app structure simplified. I have a tabbar navigator that has three screens **A B C**.

TabBar **A** is a stack navigator that includes **D** and **E**

I also have a Stack navigator that includes **F** and **G**

When I call **F** I want the TabBar to visible (on top). whats the best way to achieve that. because in this case if I go from **A** to **D** the tabbar will be on top but not if I go from **A** to **F**.

I dont want to put **F** on the same stack as **A** because **F** should be accessible from **B** and **C**, and the tabbar should be on top as well.

Perhaps a good example would be the instagram app where I can access the profile screen (**F**) from the different tabs screens and the tab is always on top

How can I achieve this with React-Navigation?

I hope I was quite clear, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing prevents screens **F** and **G** to be added in every **A**, **B** and **C** stack. It is just configuration not code duplication.

```
NavigationContainer
  Tab.Navigator
    A (Stack.Navigator)
      A (Screen)
      D (Screen)
      E (Screen)
      F (Screen)
      G (Screen)
    B (Stack.Navigator)
      B (Screen)
      F (Screen)
      G (Screen)
    B (Stack.Navigator)
      C (Screen)
      F (Screen)
      G (Screen)
```

Comment: thanks. had other diffferent use cases but was able to follow this structure